# How do I inject a script in chrome or firefox using mfc/c++

Tags: javascript, c++, firefox, visual-c++, mfc

I am working in a project where I want to inject a script in `chrome` and `firefox` web browser.
My script can change a value in text box and text fields in the web page.

As I have tried it on Internet Explorer. It is working fine. I am not getting any idea about How i can inject a script in other web browsers like `Chrome` or `Firefox`.

Can any one tell me how can I do it using `C++/MFC` for other Web Browsers?

Thank You in Advance.
Merry Christmas..

Comment: May be an XY problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Why do you want to inject a Script?

Comment: @Manuell I want to inject a script in chrome and Firefox to paste username and Password in the relative fields as I did in IE go through the link below. [Script Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704989/java-script-injection-not-working-as-desired-in-mfc-application)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Selenium won't do, removed it.

you basically have 2 solutions:

**First**: write a Chrome Extension and a Firefox extension, as you have written an IE extension. If it's just for pasting username/password, this is certainly overkill.

**second**: use [UIAutomation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). You may download a SDK (eg [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) ) and use the [Inspect tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521.aspx) to verify the accessibility support of Chrome and Firefox.